# Import XML into mc access with transform file in visual basic

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, xslt

What I would like to do is have a button import an XML file into ms access with a XSLT file.

Here is my vb code right now (which is kind of a mess, new to this):

```vb
Private Function CreateDOM()
    Dim dom
    Set dom = New DOMDocument60
    dom.async = False
    dom.validateOnParse = False
    dom.resolveExternals = False
    Set CreateDOM = dom
End Function

Private Sub impotr_Click()
    Dim strFileList() As String 'File Array
    Dim strFile As String 'Filename
    Dim intFile As Integer 'File Number
    Dim strPath As String ' Path to file folder
    Dim doc, xsl, out, str

    Set doc = CreateDOM
    doc.Load "C:\test\test.xml"
    strPath = "C:\test\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.XML")

    Set xsl = CreateDOM
    xsl.Load "C:\test\transformer.xsl"

    While strFile <> ""
           'add files to the list
          intFile = intFile + 1
          ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
          strFileList(intFile) = strFile
          strFile = Dir()
      Wend


       'see if any files were found
    If intFile = 0 Then
          MsgBox "No files found"
          Exit Sub
    End If

      'cycle through the list of files
      For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)
          On Error Resume Next
          Application.ImportXml strPath & strFileList(intFile), 2

      Next intFile


    str = doc.transformNode(xsl)

    Set out = CreateDOM
    doc.transformNodeToObject xsl, out

    MsgBox "Import Completed"
End Sub
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<iavmNotice xmlns="http://stuff.com" noticeId="138643">
   <xmlUrl>https://fakexmlurl.xml</xmlUrl>
   <htmlUrl>https://fakehtmlurl.htm</htmlUrl>
   <iavmNoticeNumber>2012-B-0080</iavmNoticeNumber>
   <title>Cisco Vulnerability</title>
   <type>B</type>
   <state>FINAL</state>
   <lastSaved>2012-08-24T10:34:13</lastSaved>
   <precoordDueDate>2012-08-23T11:00:00</precoordDueDate>
   <releaseDate>2012-08-23</releaseDate>
   <acknowledgeDate>2012-08-28</acknowledgeDate>
   <knownExploits>true</knownExploits>
   <knownDodIncidents>false</knownDodIncidents>
   <executiveSummary>Cisco incidents.</executiveSummary>
   <techOverview>
      <entry>
         <title>2012-2490</title>
         <description>Cisco ID 71.</description>
      </entry>
   </techOverview>
   <fixAction>Apply appropriate vendor update</fixAction>
   <note>&lt;b&gt;Upgrade later&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;</note>
   <tempMitStrat>
      <header>&lt;b&gt;Cisco &lt;/b&gt;</header>
      <body>&lt;br&gt;None</body>
   </tempMitStrat>
   <vulnAppsSysAndCntrmsrs>Cisco IP Communicator 8.6&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;</vulnAppsSysAndCntrmsrs>
   <references>
   <reference>
      <title>Release Notes for Cisco IP Communicator Release 8.6</title>
      <url>http://www.fakeurl.com/html</url>
   </reference>
   </references>
   <deepSightBids>
      <bid>54850</bid>
   </deepSightBids>
   <revisions>
      <revision>
         <majorNum>0</majorNum>
         <minorNum>0</minorNum>
         <type>MAJOR</type>
         <date>2012-08-23</date>
         <details>Initial Release</details>
      </revision>
      <revision>
         <majorNum>0</majorNum>
         <minorNum>1</minorNum>
         <type>MINOR</type>
         <date>2012-08-24</date>
         <details>Updated Retina Audit</details>
      </revision>
   </revisions>
   <patches>
      <patch>
         <type>V</type>
         <title>Cisco</title>
         <url>http://www.fake.com</url>
      </patch>
   </patches>
   <scanners>
      <retina>Audit 2548</retina>
   </scanners>
   <vms>
      <stigFindingSeverity>1</stigFindingSeverity>
      <affectedEnvs>B</affectedEnvs>
      <posture>1029</posture>
      <posture>1712</posture>
      <posture>59</posture>
   </vms>
</iavmNotice>
```

XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:stuff="http://stuff.com"  exclude-result-prefixes="stuff">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="stuff:entry|stuff:tempMitStrat|stuff:reference|stuff:deepSightBids|
                       stuff:revision|stuff:patch|stuff:scanners|stuff:vms">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::stuff:iavmNotice/stuff:iavmNoticeNumber"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Everything works when I import it through ms access but I need help with is the visual basic code that will transform the XML then import it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use MSXML's [XSLT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759204(v=vs.85).aspx) methods with Access' built-in [Application.ImportXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823157.aspx) specifying its *acAppendData* argument to append data from a looped list of XML files.

```vb
Public Sub TransformAndImportMultipleXMLs()
    Dim strFile As String, strPath As String
    ' REFERENCE MS XML, v6.0
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60 
    Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    strPath = "C:\test\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xml")

    ' LOAD XSL ONLY ONCE
    xslDoc.Load "C:\test\transformer.xsl"

    While strFile <> ""
        ' REINITIALIZE DOM OBJECTS
        Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        Set newDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

        ' LOAD XML SOURCE
        xmlDoc.Load strPath & strFile

        ' TRANSFORM SOURCE
        xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
        newDoc.Save "C:\test\temp.xml"

        ' APPEND TO TABLES
        Application.ImportXML "C:\test\temp.xml", acAppendData
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend

   ' RELEASE DOM OBJECTS
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Parfait! You are amazing and I love you! This worked perfectly!

Comment: is there a way to import values as comma separated? Like `<vms             <posture>1029</posture>           <posture>1712</posture>                <posture>59</posture>         </vms> be: <posture>1029, 1712, 59</posture>`

Comment: You need to adjust XSLT with a special `vms` template. See my updated answer in your other question.